# Find latest core version number

Tags: 7

How do I get the latest versions for the Drupal release installed on the server without actually downloading it?

I am writing non-Drupal code that retrieves the latest versions of the Drupal release installed on the server, and verify the server is updated or need to be updated.

Comment: In /includes/bootstrap.inc you can find `define('VERSION', '7.32');`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This will give you YOUR version installed on YOUR machine. I think OP wants to retrieve the version number of the latest release available on d.o

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for the latest Drupal version in drupal.org, not the current drupal version of the site.

Comment: I wonder how drush is getting its update information. Maybe scanning its source code might be worth for your issue.

Comment: I *really* didn't read that properly...

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 7, fetch the XML at https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/release/feed?api_version[0]=103 to get the release history. The first item's title contains the latest version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xml:base="https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/release?
    api_version[103]=103" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <channel>
    <title>Releases for Drupal core</title>
    <link>https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/release?api_version[103]=103</link>
    <description></description>
    <language>en</language>
      <item>
    <title>drupal 7.32</title>
    <link>https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.32-release-notes</link>
    <description>...
```

If you want information for all major versions (including 8 and 9), you may simply use `https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/release/feed`. You are then required to go through the items until yo find a release for the major version you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of the most recent releases of Drupal or any contrib project with the Drush command `pm-releases`.

```
$ drush pm-releases drupal
 Project  Release  Date         Status                           
 drupal   7.x-dev  2014-Oct-15  Development                      
 drupal   7.32     2014-Oct-15  Supported, Recommended, Security
```

If you want to see just the version numbers:

```
$ drush pm-releases drupal --fields=Release --field-labels=0
 7.x-dev 
 7.32
```

Regrettably, this command is missing an option to remove the dev release.  This is an oversight that we should add to Drush.

**Postscript:**

You might also want to try running the command `drush pm-updatestatus`, perhaps with the `--security-only` flag, and compare against your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old topic, but you could base your system today on the Commander API :

This URL provides the list of version of released versions of Drupal : https://repo.packagist.org/p2/drupal/core.json

This URL provides the list of security advisories associated with Drupal : [https://packagist.org/api/security-advisories/?packages[]=drupal/core](https://packagist.org/api/security-advisories/?packages%5B%5D=drupal/core)

Answer (score 0):

Since Drupal Core versions are hosted on Gitlab (see: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal and the repository is publicly accessible, I'd rely on the Gitlab API to get that piece of information.

Looking at the repository, we can see that tags are used to mention the various release versions. Using [Gitlab Tags API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html#list-project-repository-tags), we can fetch the tags into a JSON file and easily loop through it to get the latest Drupal version.

e.g. [https://git.drupalcode.org/api/v4/projects/59858/repository/tags?search=^7](https://git.drupalcode.org/api/v4/projects/59858/repository/tags?search=%5E7) will get all the D7 tags and since the default order is by updated date, the first entry of the JSON file is the tag associated to the latest D7 released version.

Comment: This should be the place to go since it is the official repository, but the tags here don't tell you any information regarding if this is a security release or not, the only api I can find with that information is here: https://packagist.org/api/security-advisories/?packages%5B%5D=drupal/core If you find any other official place, please tell me.